# Change SDE Version in ArcGIS JavaScipt API depending on connected user

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I am programming for an web editing application with ArcGIS API for JavaScript. I've published a version of ArcSDE with Feature Acces and I need to know how can I change in the web application from this version to another through the user that is connected to the application using the security manager of ArcGIS Server.

I've seen that exist a parameter gdbVersion and SetGDBVersion of featurelayer, but I don't know how to use. I need to see some example of this because the information in the documentation is not enough.

Can anyone help me? Any sample, please?
Thanks

Comment: I think through JSAPI its not possible

Comment: i definitely disagree with Sunil's comment above. take a look at the following sample
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/widget_identitymanager_client_side.html within the storeCredentials function you can see that the username of the person that signed in can be dug out using a statement like this idObject.credentials[0].userId; >>>"rick" you would have to write your own logic to use information like this to determine how to set an appropriate corresponding SDE version on the featureLayer for editing.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible! What you need first is a versioned feature class. To be bried, I assume you already know how to create versions and edit them, say using ArcMap or Arcpy. Unfortunately, there is no pre-packaged way to do it in JSAPI (AFAIK in 3.12), however, you can easily create geoprocessing services in Python that will do it though Arcpy and are accessible in JSAPI through georpocessing tasks interface (let me know if you need help with this part).

Now, assuming you have two transactional versions, call them `A` and `B`, you usually see them in ArcMap as `sde.A` and `sde.B`. By default, your published map has its `gdbVersion` empty which is basically `DEFAULT` version. However, as you have found, if you have those versions already setup, you can call `myLayer.setGDBVersion('A');` to switch the transactional version and your map should refresh itself automatically. After the first call to `setGDBVersion`, `myLayer.gdbVersion` will not be empty and will have the selected version.

Note, to get a list of versions, etc. You still need to use the geoprocessing tasks as discussed above, so the only thing you can do in JSAPI as of now, is to switch the version of your layer.

To wrap it, here is an example:

```
mapService= "http://myserver:6080/arcgis/rest/services/mymap/MapServer";
myLayer= new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(mapService,{opacity: 1});
map = new esri.Map("mapDiv");
map.on('layers-add-result', function(e){
        // just to make sure that the layer is actually loaded
        myLayer.setGDBVersion('A');
    });
map.addLayer(myLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you  are using  the security manager of ArcGIS Server  , i do not  Know  How  you can get  data  about  version of user
but  if  you are using  session  to  manage  your  user so  you  can get  version of your user form db .
set  version of user in  session  and  use this  value  in

setGDBVersion()