# Reconcile/POST version DB edits- only by selected USERS(last edited)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, versioning, arcgis-portal, reconcile

I have been reading a bunch of helpdocs/whitepapers from ESRI and could not find a solution.
My Scenario:
I have a multi-user DB and want child 1 edits concile/POST to parent 1 which then parent 1 All this works fine however I foresee a potential issue.

Child 1 version is for field crews making edits/creating data in the field.
parent1 is for our team manager to Q/A these edits which they will then reconcile/post to their parent 1 version. From there I have a script that runs nightly to reconcile/post parent1 to default.

I have created a simple script tool for the manager to execute once they verify all the edits which will only post child1 edits to parent1.

However what if there were 50 edits made and the manager only wants to push 20 of those edits to parent1 (either by username or by individual OID(row) by table). Is there a way to select only certain rows to reconcile/post perhaps by last user to edit (editor tracking is enabled) which I can implement into my script as a GetParameterasText().

I basically need to modify the reconcile manager arcpy command by only selected users or by OID by table/layer.  From what I have read it seems to be a all or nothing for reconcile/POST
Hope this makes since if not I will try to re-write question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want not a single child version, but one per user. You can then easily accept/reject a given user work. Pushing it a bit further, you could create a version per task. For instance if your user job is to "adjust street network", you would create a version per user and per street/district/town. You could manage these versions by hand or simple scripts, or you could make use of the Workflow Manager (WMX) extension.

With this approach, you accept/reject a complete version that contains logically connected items that have to exist together anyways.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea however I would have to create a new feature service to host on my server for each version and that would dramatically decrease its performance. My GIS Server is currently virtual on a piece of hardware shared by 15+  other VM's. At the moment if I followed your workflow (which I like by the way) my server would not be able to handle the increased load. I am working on a budget to get a dedicated server and if that happens this would be a viable solution.

Comment: @Joe Can't you create one service and then change the edited version? ([esri doc](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/publishing-feature-services.htm) and [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75219/change-sde-version-in-arcgis-javascipt-api-depending-on-connected-user)

Comment: PS: add the relevant tags to your question (there is no mention of Server or Portal or Desktop) to get more specific feedback

Comment: but I want need to upload each service individually with a new data store config correct? thus creating redundant data on my server which is pretty weak atm :(

Comment: @Joe No you don't have to duplicate anything. You should create just one service, pointing to sde.Default, and when your user logs-in you point just their data to their own version user123.job456. The provided links show how to do it in the web app via rest/JS

Comment: mind sharing the links? this would be great if I could do this

Comment: They are in my 1st comment